# What is the cause permission error in instapy?

Tags: python, instagram, geckodriver

error caused when the session starts, It worked in the beginning but it broke its self after a while.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\InstaPy-master\quickstart.py", line 12, in <module>
    session = InstaPy( username=insta_username, password=insta_password)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\InstaPy-master\instapy\instapy.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.logger,
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\InstaPy-master\instapy\browser.py", line 114, in set_selenium_local_session
    driver_path = geckodriver_path or get_geckodriver()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\InstaPy-master\instapy\browser.py", line 36, in get_geckodriver
    bin_path, sym_path = gdd.download_and_install()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\webdriverdownloader\webdriverdownloader.py", line 196, in download_and_install
    shutil.copy2(src_file, dest_file)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\dalto\\InstaPy\\assets\\geckodriver.exe'
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the permissions for that file?

Comment: Yes the file has no permissions as of now but i still get the error

Comment: What do you mean by _no permissions_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming because we try to open file and it is already in use, so simple option is **kill the task geckodriver.exe from task manager**. This will resolve the problem because mine is resolved.